# What does "died a year in" mean?

Tags: meaning

There is a line I do not understand:

> The first editor died a year in, leaving chaos in his wake.

What does here "died a year in" mean? Is "in" here a preposition or adverb? Why is it put at the very end of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"a year in" is short for **"a year into"** (at least in rough meaning)

or, using more words, "at a time/date around one year after commencement of X"

"chaos in his wake" - "wake" means the turbulent water behind a boat and waves jostling everything around - a phrase idiomatically means sort of "turmoil someone or something causes as it goes"

It wouldn't be uncommon for an "editor" to be making the strategic choices and steering decisions, and if the project were 'rudderless' the staff might start working at cross purposes or wrong directions , or basic materials weren't getting ordered etc.

*For a bit more of my understanding of how "in" is used here:*
"in" is at the end (edit) in a way that would be somelike a direction "North" - but instead, "ten yards inwards" "or ten minutes into the first half" shortened to "in".

Consider these imaginary dialogues: *Say I was on a phone talking to someone going into a tunnel. "Have gone into the tunnel yet?" "Yes, we are 300 yards in." ... so, like yards are a distance, time is also a distance. Often it is more like "Ten minutes into the first half, the striker scored a goal." "When? " "Ten minutes in.*

(edit)As to a part of speech, I believe, it is similar to a directional bearing.
(edit)(I am still unsure what part of speech it is when a bearing is used as a shorthand without direct reference)

What the span was/what was commenced, where 'in' was inwards from, would need some context.

It could suggest "around one year after this long term project started, the person who was the initial editor died" ...

It could also one year into the life of a new organization - the first editor ever.

It could be "the first editor during my time there died one year after I started working for that firm"

It could also mean "one year into his contract" ... referring to the elapsed time since the editor was hired.

Comment: On the one hand, *a year in* cannot literally be short for *a year into*, because the latter is not acceptable in the OP's sentence; you cannot say **The first editor died a year into.*

Comment: Having said that, I do get the sense there is a relation here. You **would** say *The first editor died a year into his term*. But also note you cannot say **The first editor died a year in his term*.

Comment: Some relevant text from OED, at the beginning of the entry for *in* as a preposition: 'The preposition expressing the relation of inclusion, situation, position, existence, or action, within limits of space, time, condition, circumstances, etc. In ancient times, expressing also (like Latin *in*) motion or direction from a point outside to one within limits; the two senses being determined by the case of the word expressing the limits, the former taking the dative (originally locative), the latter the accusative or case of direction. '

Comment: OED continues: 'These cases being subsequently levelled, this distinction ceased to be practicable, and the latter relation is now ordinarily expressed by the compound *in-to*, *into* *prep.* and *adj.*; but there are various locutions in which (either because the accompanying verb conveys the sense of motion, or through the preservation of an ancient phrase without analysis) *in* still expresses motion from without to within.'

Comment: But I have been unable to find a relevant sense for *in* in the OED's entry for that preposition, one that would fit *The first editor died a year in*. There *is* a relevant sense listed in the OED's entry for *into*:

*11. Introducing a period of time to the midst of which anything advances or continues.*

Some examples from OED: 

*The drizzling rain..continued far into the night.* |
*Far on into life [we] were glad when any chance brought us together again.* |
 *It was well into the next season before they were back.*

Comment: So my best guess is that, fundamentally, you are probably right in that [1] *The first editor died a year in* is the result of an ellipsis of something like  [2] *The first editor died a year into his term*. But the remnants of case complicate matters here. In [2], because *his term* would have been in the accusative, we use *into* (see the discussion from OED, above). However, after ellipsis, we are left with *into* that is not followed by a noun phrase that would have been in the accusative, and that looks wrong. So we change *into* back to *in*. But this is just a speculation.

Comment: @linguisticturn  perhaps I should delete my answer as I am no more able to document it than you are.  Say I was on a phone talking to someone going into a tunnel.  "Have gone into the tunnel yet?" "Yes, we are 300 yards in."  ... so, like yards are a distance, time is also  a distance.  Often it is more like "Ten minutes into the first half, the striker scored a goal."   "When? "  "Ten minutes in."

Comment: I would go out on a limb and describe "in" here as a postposition, working functionally the same as "ago" but with a different meaning—rather than time before current time, it means time since some start time.

Comment: @Tom22 Yes; in fact, if I'm reading e.g. OED correctly, *in* and *into* are about spatial relations first, and about temporal relations sort of by extension.

Comment: @nohat I think that's a very interesting suggestion! CGEL (p. 632) treats as similar *ago* and *on*: [18 ] a. *She died [ten years ago].* b. *[Ten years on] nothing had changed.* Perhaps the *in* in *ten years in* is another example of whatever *ago* and *on* (in this sense) are examples of.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the first editor died a year into his job of being the editor, meaning that they had to find someone to fill the position that he left.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the phrase:

> The first editor died a year in, leaving chaos in his wake

means the first editor died in the same time period of his employment as editor for whatever he was editing. His death left the unfinished work that he was employed for in chaos.

Hope this is helpful!